Triplet of $S_3$
Suppose we have an $S_3$ permuting three items $v=(x~y~z)$. Then, in the reducible triplet representation the elements would look like,
$$
(123) = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix},~
(12)= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix},
$$
and all other elements...
One can find that all elements are simultaneously diagonalisible via a matrix,
$$
U = \begin{pmatrix}
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} & -\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} \\
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \\
\end{pmatrix},
$$
so that
$$
U \, g_i \, U^T = \mathrm{diag}(D_{2\times 2},~D_1).
$$
For example,
$$
U \, (123) \, U^T = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & 0 \\
 \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right), \\
U \, (12) \, U^T =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right).
$$
In the new representation the elements of $S_3$ would act on a new triplet $v^\prime$ (due to transformation by $U$) as on a doublet and a singlet.
Now, is it possible to construct a triplet in a such way that it would decompose into a doublet and a sign representation? My naive guess would be to consider the character table of the $S_3$ group and realise that,
$$
1^\prime:~ (123) = 1,~ (12) = -1. 
$$
So that,
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & 0 \\
 \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right), ~~ \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \color{red}{-1} \\
\end{array}
\right).
$$
I assume this is a wrong approach.

I didn't check the calculations, but surely something like this can be done. The usual permutation action yields a 3-dimensional representation that decomposes as a direct sum of the trivial 1-d rep and an irreducible 2-d rep. Nothing stop you from forming the direct sum of that 2-d rep and the sign rep!

That 2x2 block in the matrix representing that 3-cycle sure looks like the matrix of a rotation by 120 degrees, doesn't it? Similare that 2x2 block of the 2-cycle is a reflection as it flips the first coordinate. Those are symmetries of a suitable equilateral triangle, which is what you want here!

Well, I checked that the last two generators do indeed form the $S_3$ group, however, If we re-define the generator with the diagonal form we get into the "basis" of a trivial representation and a doublet representation. To me this sounds like something is wrong; though, to be honest, my knowledge of Group Theory is limited.

Do you know how to use the inner products of characters? That gives a quick way of checking that the second 3-d rep has no trivial component.

If I understand correctly we get $<\chi^{3D}> = (3~0~-1)$. Then, the inner products with the trivial and sign representations produce "0" ?! I am probably doing something wrong since that would indicate that these representations are orthogonal?

The sign character $\sigma$ takes values $(1,1,-1)$ at conjugacy classes of sizes $(1,2,3)$. Therefore the inner product is
$$
\langle\sigma,\chi\rangle=\frac16\left(1\cdot3+2\cdot1\cdot0+3\cdot(-1)\cdot(-1)\right)=1.
$$ So the sign character is there with multipicity $1$.
On the other hand the trivial character $\chi_0$ takes values $1$ everywhere, so
$$\langle\chi_0,\chi\rangle=\frac16\left(1\cdot3+2\cdot1\cdot0+3\cdot1\cdot(-1)\right)=0.
$$

Ah, right! Thank you! I got confused since I looked at another character table (rather the one I had written on a paper) and the dimension 3 and 2 conjugacy classes were interchanged.

Feel free to post a summary as an answer, if you think these calculations answer the question. I'm not 100 per cent sure what the question was, so I probably shouldn't answer. And the comments will get deleted at some point anyway. They are good for (extended) hints and pointers, but poor as answers.
